# Enabling Lightning for Outlook 365

Tags: lightning, outlook

We have currently installed Lightning for Outlook 365 on a mailbox we get the following error:

> Ask your admin for permission to log email

What kind of permission is needed to log email? Our users are already able to create and send emails on Salesforce. Additionally, do we need any separate user to install Lightning for Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Setup, enter Email to Salesforce in the Quick Find box, then select Email to Salesforce.

1. Click Edit.
2. Select Active.
3. Click Save